# List items don't align the same

Tags: html, css, list

Hope you guys and girls can help me out here. 
I want all the list items align the same at the left side (see image for example)

[Example what I want is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B77k1.png)

And this is my code

```css
.feature-stack {
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
  border: solid 3px;
}

.features ul.features-stack {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.features ul.features-stack ul {}

.features ul.features-stack li:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.feature-content ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="features-stack">

  <li class="feature-item">
    <div class="feature-content">
      <h5>Polyethene</h5>
      <li>Test Test</li>
      <li>Test Test</li>
      <li>Test Test</li>
      <li>Test Test</li>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="feature-item">
    <div class="feature-content">
      <h5>Other virgin plastic</h5>
      <li>Test Test</li>
      <li>Test Test</li>
      <li>Test Test</li>
      <li>Test Test</li>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="feature-item">
    <div class="feature-content">
      <h5>Polypropylene</h5>
      <li>Test Test</li>
      <li>Test Test</li>
      <li>Test Test</li>
      <li>Test Test</li>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

So I want them to align the same and that the circles are gone.
Hope I have given you guys enough information, otherwise let me know so I can give you more information.

Thanks

Comment: its proper working whats wrong

Comment: you should put `<li>`tags inside `>ul>` tags not div

Comment: To remove the dots use .features-stack {
 list-style-type: none;
}

Comment: Maybe relevant, maybe not: you should not mix `<div>`s and `<li>`s like you are doing. An `<li>` only makes sense inside a `<ul>` or `<ol>` parent, it can't ever have a `<div>` parent.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `ul {list-style-type:none;}` does the trick:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
}

.feature-stack {      
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
  border: solid 3px;
}

.features ul.features-stack {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.features ul.features-stack ul {}

.features ul.features-stack li:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.feature-content ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="features-stack">

  <li class="feature-item">
    <div class="feature-content">
      <h5>Polyethene</h5>
      <li>Test Test</li>
      <li>Test Test</li>
      <li>Test Test</li>
      <li>Test Test</li>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="feature-item">
    <div class="feature-content">
      <h5>Other virgin plastic</h5>
      <li>Test Test</li>
      <li>Test Test</li>
      <li>Test Test</li>
      <li>Test Test</li>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="feature-item">
    <div class="feature-content">
      <h5>Polypropylene</h5>
      <li>Test Test</li>
      <li>Test Test</li>
      <li>Test Test</li>
      <li>Test Test</li>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add below css to your style sheet:

```
 ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.Heading {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And in your HTML just replace heading tag(H5) with list tag(li). Please find below the code:

```
<ul class="features-stack">

                        <li class="feature-item">
                            <div class="feature-content">
                                <li class="Heading">Polyethene</li>
                                    <li>Test Test</li>
                                    <li>Test Test</li>
                                    <li>Test Test</li>
                                    <li>Test Test</li> 
                            </div>
                        </li>
                <br/>
                        <li class="feature-item">
                            <div class="feature-content">                                    
                                <li class="Heading">Other virgin plastic</li>
                                    <li>Test Test</li>
                                    <li>Test Test</li>
                                    <li>Test Test</li>
                                    <li>Test Test</li>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                   <br/>
                        <li class="feature-item">
                            <div class="feature-content">                                   
                                <li class="Heading">Polypropylene</li>
                                    <li>Test Test</li>
                                    <li>Test Test</li>
                                    <li>Test Test</li>
                                    <li>Test Test</li>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
```

I have tested the above code and its working fine.